Basic word counting test for special input
Objective.
The program will read a line of text from the user and print out the number of times each word appears in the input.
Requirements.

Change string to have all lowercase lettersto_lowercase(char *str)
Loop through the string and change all the letters to lowercase
Search for words already found: find_word(char words[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], int size, char *word)
Search through all the words already found and see if a match exists with the current word
If a match is found, return the index of the match
If no match is found then return -1

The main function.

Provided input (for user input), found_words (a matrix that holds the found words), counts(an array that holds counts at an index)
Prompt user to enter a sentence
Receive the sentence via standard input using fgets
If the last character of the input is a newline, then remove it
Use strtok to tokenize the input based on space (" ")
While strtok finds a new word continue to loop through the words in the sentence
Call find_words with the current word and the found words
If the return is -1, copy the current word to the found_words array and increase count for the max index
If the return is not -1, then increase the associated value in counts
Increase word_count
Print out the counts for each word

Steps to Complete.

Implement the requirements
Compile and test the program
Create 1 user test case, use the description in the test case to guide the creation of the test case.
Run /challenge/tester
Get flag

main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 100
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 50

// Helper function to convert a string to lowercase
void to_lowercase(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
}

// Check if word already exists in the list
int find_word(char words[][MAX_WORD_LEN], int word_count, char *word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(words[i], word) == 0) {
            return i; // return the index of the word if found
        }
    }
    return -1; // return -1 if not found
}

int main() {
    char input[1000];
    char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int counts[MAX_WORDS] = {0};
    int word_count = 0;

    // Prompt the user for input
    printf("Enter a line of text: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    // Remove the newline character at the end of the input if it exists
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    if (len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n') {
        input[len - 1] = '\0';
    }

    // Tokenize the input by spaces
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        to_lowercase(token); // convert token to lowercase

        int index = find_word(words, word_count, token);

        if (index == -1) {
            // New word, add it to the list
            strcpy(words[word_count], token);
            counts[word_count]++;
            word_count++;
        } else {
            // Existing word, increment its count
            counts[index]++;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Output the word counts
    printf("word counts:");
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        printf(" %s: %d", words[i], counts[i]);
        if (i < word_count - 1) {
            printf(" "); // Space between words
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

---------------[  User Tests  ]---------------
User utest5.2.1: ✔ PASS  - Basic word counting test with special input ran in 0.01s
User utest5.2.1: FAIL  - Basic word counting test with special input 
        Test Desc        : Tests word counting with special input 'Hello world Hello\n\n' and case insensitivity
        Command          : /challenge/modelGood.bin 
        Program Input    : 'Hello world Hello\n\n\n'
        Expected Output  : ['word counts: hello: 2 world: 1\n']
        Test ran in      : 0.01s
        Failed to find in output   : word counts: hello: 2 world: 1
        Closest match is at line 2 : hello: 2
--------<[ utest5.2.1   (marked output of /tmp/test_output/utest5.2.1_actual_normalized.output) ]>--------
1  enter a line of text: word counts:
2  hello: 2
         ↑↑↑↑↑
3  world: 1
↑ EOF ↑

User utest5.2.1: ✔ PASS  - Basic word counting test with special input ran in 0.01s

---------------[ System Tests ]---------------
System stest5.2.1: ✔ PASS  - Test for the counts for the above input ran in 0.01s
System stest5.2.2: ✔ PASS  - Test input for the expected counts  ran in 0.01s

Summary: 4 tests passed, 1 tests failed
Too many failures to receive flag

I am unable to resolve this error:
User utest5.2.1: FAIL  - Basic word counting test with special input 
        Test Desc        : Tests word counting with special input 'Hello world Hello\n\n' and case insensitivity
        Command          : /challenge/modelGood.bin 
        Program Input    : 'Hello world Hello\n\n\n'
        Expected Output  : ['word counts: hello: 2 world: 1\n']
        Test ran in      : 0.01s
        Failed to find in output   : word counts: hello: 2 world: 1
        Closest match is at line 2 : hello: 2
--------<[ utest5.2.1   (marked output of /tmp/test_output/utest5.2.1_actual_normalized.output) ]>--------
1  enter a line of text: word counts:
2  hello: 2
         ↑↑↑↑↑
3  world: 1
↑ EOF ↑


When you used a debugger, what was the first line that didn't do what you expected?

It looks like you are printing output in wrong format (see Expected Output: ['word counts: hello: 2 world: 1\n']). Maybe you don't want to print enter a line of text: and you want to put word counts in one line)

Why is the prompt in the code Enter a line of text:  but enter a line of text:  in the test output? Has the code changed after the tests?

Aside: (not OP's main problem): char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN]; is conceptually misleading.  strlen() returns the length, yet the size needed for such a string is + 1.  I'd use char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN + 1]; and char words[][MAX_WORD_LEN+1] or the like.

strcpy(words[word_count], token); risks buffer overflow as the string pointed to by token may be much bigger than words[word_count].


I am unable to resolve this error:

One thing certainly looks weird "program will read a line of text from the user" along with special input 'Hello world Hello\n\n'.
The special input looks like 2 lines.
Code only ever reads 1 line.  Instead read multiples lines:
// fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL) {
  ...
}

Then print the output.
